# tmux chain keyboard shortcuts, or equivalent for screen's `bind -c` + `command -c`

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

One nice feature of screen is its ability to assign keyboard shortcuts to groups called "classes".  With `bind -c`, you could assign that shortcuts to a particular class, and binding `command -c <class>` to a key allowed you to select that class.  This allowed multi-tier keyboard shortcuts.  For example, I used the `x` key to select a class dedicated common commands.  By having these launcher shortcuts in their own class, it is possible to use mnemonic keys without worrying about conflicts with the normal set of key-bindings.  Is there any way to replicate this feature in `tmux`?

#### Example

```
# from my .screenrc
bind -c execute o screen -t imap 10 offlineimap.sh -o
bind -c execute m screen -t mpd ncmpcpp
bind -c execute w screen -t vw vimwiki
# ... more application launchers 
bind x command -c execute
```

Usage: <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> enters the launcher key class, where I put all my application keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After understanding better what you are trying to do, I think a short bash script is the best way to go (sorry, I don't think a `tmux`-only solution similar to `screen` command classes exists):

In `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key x command-prompt -p "launch what?" " "run-shell \"tmux-launcher %%\""
```

`tmux-launcher` should be an executable shell script somewhere in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in 
  o) tmux new-window -n imap -t 10 offlineimap.sh -o ;;
  m) tmux new-window -n mod ncmpcpp ;;
  w) tmux new-window -n vw vimwiki ;;
esac
```

One drawback is that you must type return after the letter that selects the window to create.

Answer (score 3):

I was [recently informed of the `switch-client` approach to this](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sessionist/pull/21#issuecomment-344241576)

to bind `join-pane` to `prefix + t*`

```
tmux bind-key t switch-client -Ttable1
tmux bind-key -Ttable1 '*' join-pane
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `tmux` does not support command classes like this. However, it might be possible to accomplish a task for which `screen` command classes are suitable in a different way in `tmux`.

Here's an example from the `screen` man page, where windows whose indices are higher than 9 may be selected:

```
 bind -c demo1 0 select 10
 bind -c demo1 1 select 11
 bind -c demo1 2 select 12
 bindkey "^B" command -c demo1
```

The command class 'demo1' lets you select window 12 using "Ctrl-a Ctrl-B 2" (or would it be just "Ctrl-B 2"? I'm rusty with `screen` configuration).

In `tmux`, you could select window 12 using "Ctrl-b w c", where "Ctrl-b w" is the default key binding to invoke the `choose-window` command, and 'c' is the shortcut for selecting window 12 from the interactive menu of windows.

So, my general advice is to explore the `tmux` command set to see if there is a `tmux` idiom available for what you would accomplish using command classes in `screen`. If you have a specific task in mind, I encourage you to post it as a separate question.

Comment: I described one use case in my question, which is to have a separate prefix key for application launchers, essentially giving the application launchers their own "name-"/"key-"space instead of hunting for unused, hard-to-remember keys among the default set.

Comment: Please post an excerpt from your `.screenrc` file; it's possible you could adapt a solution in `tmux` using the `command-prompt` command.

Comment: I've edited the question.