# tmux bind-key with two keys

Tags: tmux

In `~/.tmux.conf`, with

```
 bind-key v split-window "vim"
```

I can launch vim in a split window.

how I can use two keys in a tmux `bind-key` ?
Example:

```
 bind-key vG split-window "vim +$"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot. `tmux` only allows single-key bindings (either alone, using `bind-key -n`, or following the prefix key).

However, you might try binding "v" to an invocation of `command-prompt`:

```
bind-key v command-prompt "tmux-vim.bash %%"
```

where `tmux-vim.bash` looks something like

```
if [ $1 = "G" ]; then
    tmux split-window "vim +$"
fi
```

Then, after typing  v to get to the command prompt, you would just type "G" and press Enter. "G" would be passed as the argument to `tmux-vim.bash`, and that script would take care of executing the `tmux` command you (originally) wanted to associate with "vG".

Comment: [tmux chain keyboard shortcuts, or equivalent for screen's `bind -c` + `command -c`](http://superuser.com/questions/424160/tmux-chain-keyboard-shortcuts-or-equivalent-for-screens-bind-c-command)

Comment: You'd think I would have remembered answering that well enough to link to it myself :)

Answer (score 9):

### Answer

There is only one right solution for it:

```
    # you can use "vim +$" as well, but I don't think that +$ prefix have any sense without the file path argument...
    bind -T multiKeyBindings G split-window "vim" 
    bind v switch-client -T multiKeyBindings
```

If you want the possibility to pass custom arguments, you should use this one instead:

```
    bind -T multiKeyBindings G command-prompt 'split-window "vim %%"'
    bind v switch-client -T multiKeyBindings
```

More examples:

```
    # Toggle maximizing of current pane by typing PREFIX mm 
    bind -T multiKeyBindings m resize-pane -Z
    bind m switch-client -T multiKeyBindings

    # or without PREFIX
    bind -T multiKeyBindings m resize-pane -Z
    bind -n m switch-client -T multiKeyBindings

    # rename current window by typing PREFIX mr
    bind -T multiKeyBindings r command-prompt 'rename-window %%'
    bind -n m switch-client -T multiKeyBindings
```

### The notable thing

You should use a unique key tablet's name for each multi keybinding. Example:

```
    bind -T multiKeyBinding1 G split-window "vim"
    bind v switch-client -T multiKeyBinding1

    bind -T multiKeyBinding2 m resize-pane -Z
    bind -n m switch-client -T multiKeyBinding2
```

Comment: For those wondering what is going on: A new keytable called "multiKeyBindings" is created. prefix + v will make tmux change ("switch-client") to this keytable. The other command can only be triggered when G is pressed in this keytable.

Comment: Might be a good idea to name them e.g. `MultiKeyBinding_v`, `MultiKeyBinding_m`, etc...

Answer (score 4):

As @chepner said, you cannot do this *directly*.  What you can do is bind `v` to create a binding for `G` that does what you want and then unbinds itself.

`bind-key v bind-key -n G split-window "vim +$" \\; unbind -n G`

There are a couple of important things to note with this approach:

1. This will conflict with existing top-level bindings (in this case `G`);  If you want to have something bound to `G` and something else bound to `vG` your unbinding step needs to restore the original binding.
2. `tmux` will segfault if your `.tmux.conf` includes a `bind-key` statement that is too long.  If this becomes a problem, you can work around it by putting your context switching in bash scripts and then bind a key to run those scripts.

For a more involved example, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hjdivad/d7f79b45ac2922336fec).

Answer (score 3):

After 2015, yes you can do this.

They add a new argument `-T key-table` to `switch-client` command to support this feature.
Here's the commit: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/bded7437064c76dd6cf4e76e558d826859adcc79

Maybe they released this feature at version 2.1, but I did not saw any release notes mentioned this.

Here's the way to archive this goal:

task: do something like: bind-key vG split-window "vim +$"
code:

```
bind-key -T prefix v switch-client -T prefix_v
bind-key -T prefix_v G split-window "vim +$"
```

Comment: Why the `-n` doesn't work on these bindings?

Comment: I really need to know how, if you know please tag me.

Comment: @Niing sorry, I don't understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the `command-prompt` approach suggested on the other answers, you can have a second set of mappings using a different prefix:

```
     prefix key
         Set the key accepted as a prefix key.

     prefix2 key
         Set a secondary key accepted as a prefix key.
```

Thus you could do the following:

```
set -g prefix C-v
bind-key G split-window "vim +$"
```

to map to `c-v g` instead of `c-b vG`. The downside is that it will shadow any default mapping, as it will also be accessible through `c-b g`.